# Should I change all the URL paths on my website to include keywords for SEO and should I rename my cart and checkout pages too?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, url, search-engines

I'm trying to make my site as SEO optimized as possible and have a question.

Do I change the name of my "cart.php" and "checkout.php" pages to have keywords in them?

For example, here's the **current names** of all my pages:

- `index.php`
- `about-me.php`
- `portfolio.php`
- `news.php`
- `store.php`
- `item-details.php`
- `cart.php`
- `checkout.php`
- `terms-and-conditions.php`

Let's say that my name is **Bob Doe** and what I'm trying to sell is **paintings**.

Here is what I plan on **renaming them to**.

- `index.php`
- `about-me.php` -> *`about-bob-doe.php`*
- `portfolio.php` -> *`portfolio-bob-doe.php`*
- `news.php` -> *`news-bob-doe.php`*
- `store.php` -> *`store-buy-paintings.php`*
- `item-details.php` -> *`store-painting-info.php`*
- `cart.php` -> **Should I rename this?**
- `checkout.php` -> **Should I rename this?**
- `terms-and-conditions.php`

Am I doing the right thing here?

Should I be renaming my pages? Will renaming "cart" and "checkout" make a difference?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this would help SEO these days?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller idk, I thought google takes the urls into consideration. Is this not the case anymore?

Comment: I got the idea from guides like this (page 8-9): http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: That guide is copyright 2010 at the bottom.   You should find newer sources for SEO advice.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller good point! Where's a good resource for the latest SEO advice?

Comment: That guide is reasonably sound IMO. However, neither does it suggest that a URL of the form `about-bod-doe.php` would necessarily be any better than a URL like `about-me.php`? There is also an inherent (SEO) risk with _changing_ a URL structure.

Comment: That guide doesn't actually look too bad having looked closer.   It doesn't actually say to stuff keywords into URLs.  It says "Use words in URLs" and "avoid using excessive keyword".   Your URLs already had good words for SEO and you are proposing stuffing keywords in them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Kk I'll go with the more human readable options instead of keywords. Thanks for the advice!